# External calculation within opl

Tags: cplex, opl, docplex

I'm implementing a CP model with cplex but within the steps I want some data to be calculated in a function or some similar form then resolve the model using the result.

What I need to calculate is the angle between two points with a third one as the center point e.g.

**Input:**
`x=(5, 0), y=(0, 0), z=(0, 5)`

**Output:**

`Angle = 90.0 degrees or 1.571 rad`

[Check this link for more details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points) Or [this link](https://manivannan-ai.medium.com/find-the-angle-between-three-points-from-2d-using-python-348c513e2cd)

In python the function would look like this:

```
def calculate_angle(
        first_point: Vector, center_point: Vector,
        second_point: Vector) -> float:
    """ Calculate the angel between three points. """
    # Change to scalars
    a = np.array(first_point.as_list())
    b = np.array(center_point.as_list())
    c = np.array(second_point.as_list())

    # Calculate vector differences
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    # Find the angle in degrees
    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    cosine_angle = np.clip(cosine_angle, -1, 1)
    angle_radians = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
    return angle_radians
```

Is there a way to use the arccos in opl? or call the python function in the model file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OPL scripting you can call any function in java as can be seen in this example: https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplscripting/blob/main/IloOplCallJava.mod

```
execute
{
  
var convert180toRadian = IloOplCallJava("java.lang.Math","toRadians", "", 180);
writeln("180 degrees in radian : ",convert180toRadian);
                
}   

/*
180 degrees in radian : 3.141592654
*/  

execute
{
var title="title";
var msg="hello";  

IloOplCallJava("javax.swing.JOptionPane", "showMessageDialog",
"(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;I)V", 
null, msg, title, 1);    
}  

execute{ 
writeln("5 random numbers");
var rnd = IloOplCallJava("java.util.Random", "<init>", "()");
rnd.setSeed(1); 
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
{                             
 var t = rnd.nextDouble();
 writeln(t);
}
writeln("Gaussian");
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
{                             
 var t = rnd.nextGaussian();
 writeln(t);
}
}
```

If you want to call your python code you can use IloOplExec in scripting as can be seen at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/barchart.mod

```
{string} options={"OPL" , "Python", "Java", "C++/C/C#", "Julia", "Other"};
float percent[options]=[32, 25, 16,  14, 4, 9];
string lastOption=last(options);

execute
{

var o=new IloOplOutputFile("c:\\temp\\parambarchart.txt");
o.writeln("Which API do you use when you call CPLEX ?");
o.writeln("CPLEX API");
o.writeln("% of use");

for(var i in options) 
{
 o.write(i);
 if (i!=lastOption) o.write(",");
}
o.writeln();

for(var i in options) 
{
 o.write(percent[i]);
 if (i!=lastOption) o.write(",");
}
o.writeln();
o.close();

IloOplExec("C:\\Python36\\python.exe c:\\temp\\displaybarchart.py",false);

}
```

and in displaybarchart.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

f = open("c://temp//parambarchart.txt", "r")
title=f.readline()
xlabel=f.readline()
ylabel=f.readline()
xstring=f.readline()
ystring=f.readline()
f.close();

x =  xstring.split(",")
values = [float(i) for i in ystring.split(",")]

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]

plt.bar(x_pos, values, color='green')
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.title(title)

plt.xticks(x_pos, x)

plt.show()
```